# Dealing with trailing decimals at the end of a DateTime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, iso8601

I am trying to convert the string below into a datetime object using datetime.strptime, and I just can't seem to figure out **.746Z** at the end.

```
datetime_str = '2022-04-21T08:17:49.746Z'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%z')
print(datetime_object)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Hi - I think your reference is a more complete answer to avoiding having to use strptime(). But they would have to dig through it to get to this specific questions about using strptime(). If not, I can delete! Thanks!

Comment: strptime is fine, actually you're just missing the %f for the fractional seconds. I just wanted to link the other question which is a bit more general. You might not want to delete your question, since other people might stumble across your specific problem  ;-)